# Ruby: How to get colors in testrb

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9

Is there any way to get colors via testrb that does not involve adding test-unit to the gemfile and using bundle exec on 1.9 (everything colored in 1.8)?

- `ruby test/xxx_test.rb` -> colors
- `testrb test/xxx_test.rb` -> no colors
- Add test-unit to the gemfile and `bundle exec testrb test/xxx_test.rb` -> colors

Answer (score 0):

`--use-color=yes` does the trick... good thing its not documented :D